# How to change web page content without removing any style/css/graphics

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the content in a page through a refresh button, using JavaScript or jQuery. I want to change the content in a table, but any command I use removes parts of the table and leaves the new content in white.

so far, i' ve tried `change()`, `replaceWith()`, `load()`, `text()` but all of those remove parts of the table. With `document.write()` it prints in a new page.

Is there any command I can use so to replace an already written table with new content?

**UPDATE:**

Code

```
<script>
            var result = []; 
            var k = 0;
            var jsonObject = JSON.parse(eventsJson);
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#priceInfoB").on("click", function(){
                    //alert(jsonObject.events.event[0].name);
                    for (i=0;i<4;i++){
                        if (jsonObject.events.event[i].isFree == "true"){
                            result[k] = jsonObject.events.event[i].name;
                            k++;
                        }
                    }
                    $("#events").text(result[0] + result[1]);
                    $('#myTable').remove();
                });
            });
```

```
<table id="myTable">
            <tr class="head">
                <th></th>
                <th>New York</th>
                <th>Chicago</th>
                <th>San Francisco</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>BLABLA</th>
                <td>Sat, 4 Feb 2012<br />11am - 2pm</td>
                <td>Sat, 3 Mar 2012<br />11am - 2pm</td>
                <td>Sat, 17 Mar 2012<br />11am - 2pm</td>
            </tr>

var eventsJson='{"events":{"event":[{"id":"1","name":"A Poetic Perspective","isFree":"true","locations":[{"location":"New York","eventDate":"2015-05-02","eventTime":"14:00"},{"location":"Chicago","eventDate":"2015-05-01","eventTime":"14:00"},{"location":"San Francisco","eventDate":"2015-06-01","eventTime":"15:00"}],"descr":"Vivamus elementum, diam eget ullamcorper fermentum, ligula libero euismod massa, quis condimentum tellus lacus sit."},{"id":"2","name":"Walt Whitman at War","isFree":"false","locations":[{"location":"New York","eventDate":"2015-07-02","eventTime":"14:00"},{"location":"Chicago","eventDate":"2015-07-01","eventTime":"14:00"},{"location":"San Francisco","eventDate":"2015-08-01","eventTime":"15:00"}],"descr":"Donec convallis eu metus eget dictum. Etiam non lobortis dui."},{"id":"3","name":"Found Poems & Outsider Poetry","isFree":"false","locations":[{"location":"New York","eventDate":"2015-06-02","eventTime":"11:00"},{"location":"Chicago","eventDate":"2015-07-01","eventTime":"14:00"},{"location":"San Francisco","eventDate":"2015-06-01","eventTime":"15:00"}],"descr":"Ut fermentum, elit vel iaculis viverra, dui libero ultrices nibh, ut ornare."},{"id":"4","name":"Natural Death: An Exploration","isFree":"true","locations":[{"location":"New York","eventDate":"2015-05-02","eventTime":"14:00"},{"location":"Chicago","eventDate":"2015-05-01","eventTime":"14:00"},{"location":"San Francisco","eventDate":"2015-06-01","eventTime":"15:00"}],"descr":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent aliquet urna ut tortor consequat."}]}}';
```

Comment: `$('#myTable').remove()`

Comment: Adding new elements to the page, whatever they are, will use existing linked css or style tags in the page.  You mustn't be using the correct class names, or you're adding the new elements incorrectly.

Comment: What data you're trying to replace in table? Whole table, some columns, all rows? Would be great if you could set a fiddle to clearly explain the problem.

Comment: If you are going to post a jsfiddle link then **please** post the same html/css/javascript there.  Fiddle examples can be deleted, which would make this page useless.  This site isn't about answering a question and being done with it.  It's here for future use as well.

Comment: this command removes my whole table :p

Comment: What is `#events`?  It's not in your markup.

Comment: eventsJson is a JSON object i want to take elements from and load them to the table. It consists of several arrays

Comment: And you want to add the JSON object's info inside the table...?

Comment: yes! dont mind the  $("#events").text(result[0] + result[1]); code is something else i just do in my page..i just want to refresh my whole table (without losing it) with all JSON components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will update the table from the supplied JSON...

http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/eemxvu0z/

**HTML**

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr class="head">
        <th></th>
        <th>New York</th>
        <th>Chicago</th>
        <th>San Francisco</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>BLABLA</th>
        <td>Sat, 4 Feb 2012<br />11am - 2pm</td>
        <td>Sat, 3 Mar 2012<br />11am - 2pm</td>
        <td>Sat, 17 Mar 2012<br />11am - 2pm</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
var data = JSON.parse(eventsJson);

function showEvent(id) {
    for (var i in data.events.event) {
        if (data.events.event[i].id == id) {
            var thisEvent = data.events.event[i];
            var head = "<tr class=\"head\"><th></ht>";
            var row = "<tr><th>" + thisEvent.name + "</th>";
            for (var l in thisEvent.locations) {
                var thisLocation = thisEvent.locations[l];
                head += "<th>" + thisLocation.location + "</th>";
                row += "<td>" + thisLocation.eventDate + "<br/>" + thisLocation.eventTime + "</td>";
            }
            head += "</tr>";
            row += "</tr>";
            $("#myTable").html(head + row);
        }
    }
}

showEvent(4);  // for example
```

Basically, just rebuild the html for the table from the supplied data and use `$("#myTable").html(html);` to update it.  I expect you'll be using an event, such as a select value change, to trigger the table update, so just use the `showEvent(id);` function call to update it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. i use the onClick event on a button to trigger the update

Comment: @user2010686: Please accept the answer if it solved your question. It might be helpful to others too.